# Can you re-use update values for on duplicate key updates?

Tags: mysql

So let's say you have column A,B,C. On duplicate key, let's say you do A = {some statement here}, B = {some statement here}, and C= New_A + New_B. Can I use what would be the new values of A and B in order to determine the new value of C, or do I have to retype the expressions for the new A and B? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it. If you do:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    A = A + 1, B = B * 2,
    C = A + B
```

I believe the updates are executed left to right. So when it gets to `C = A + B`, `A` and `B` contain the new values.

Comment: `C = VALUES(A) + VALUES(B)` would be a bit more deterministic, since the [`VALUES()`function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) is guaranteed to provide the new values, while the left-to-right behavior is more of an (un)fortunate accident.  In standard SQL, `UPDATE t1 SET b = a, a = b` transposes the values of a and b, but in MySQL it sets them both to a, because it's taking the value of "old a" but "new b" on the right hand side of the assignment operator.  Reorder the query and the code breaks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The `VALUES()` function picks up the values that would have been inserted into the columns if there weren't a duplicate, it doesn't get the new values from the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: Ohhh, we're talking about *those* "new values."  I misunderstood the question to mean the new values from the new insert, not the newly-modified values after the updates.  In which case, of course, you're completely correct.